# php regex find part of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find a string inside curly braces that can appear in many variations.

i.e. 
In the following string i'm searching for the word **Link**

> asdasd{Link1111:TAG}\r\n         {TAG:Link2sds}

I'm using the following command: `$pattern = "/{(Link.*?)}|{(.*Link.*?)}/";`

and the result is:

```
{array} [3]
 0 => {array} [2]
     0 = "{Link1:TAG}"
     1 = "{TAG:Link2}"
 1 = {array} [2]
     0 = "Link1:TAG"
     1 = ""
 2 = {array} [2]
     0 = ""
     1 = "TAG:Link2"
```

I'm expecting only the first array without the curly braces...what am i missing with the regex?
thx.

Comment: Just use `$pattern = "/{(.*?Link.*?)}/";` and `print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: yeap! spot on...if you want to submit it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `/{(.*?Link.*?)}/` and your matches will be in index 1

```
<?php

$str = "asdasd{Link1111:TAG}\r\n {TAG:Link2sds}";

$pattern = "/{(.*?Link.*?)}/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Your [eval](https://eval.in/572830)

Comment: Wrong! You can't use `.*?` before `Link`. Consider the string `{toto123:tag} {Link111:tag}`. *Remember that the regex engine walks from left to right and try to succeed at each position.*

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` is global and finds all matches. If you want to find it just once use `preg_match`.

Demo: https://eval.in/572825

The `0` index in your current example is all matches. The `1` is the first capture group `Link.*?`, and the `2` is your second capture group `.*Link.*?`.